# Is this an authentic image of a UFO sighting in Canary Islands (1976)?

Tags: ufo, optical-illusions

According to Wikipedia, a strange 40 minute unidentified flying object or an unexplainable phenomena occured on June 22, 1976 in the Canary islands. The phenomena (object) was observed in multiple locations including Tenerife, La Palma, La Gomera, Grand Canary and by a ship at sea. Moroever, the UFO was witnessed by several hundred people, including both civilian and military personnel.

An image of what appears to be attached to several articles alleged that the following photo was the UFO or phenomena observed

[image]

Some websites relating this photo with the event are:

- https://amazing1photosfromtheworld.blogspot.com/2019/02/canary-isles-sightings-1976.html
- https://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread1257912/pg1
- https://www.openminds.tv/canary-islands-mass-ufo-sighting-1976/38122

Moreover, some Spanish newspaper have covered this event including this photograph in the main headline
[image]

The newspaper above (though I couldn't find it elsewhere) claims that the image above (also claiming that it was during the event that occurred) were that of a UGM-73 Poseidon missile (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UGM-73_Poseidon) but after searching again about these missiles on that day of the event on google I came up with nothing. Another low-resolution image of the headline of a newspaper is shown below:

[image]

> (1) Is this image truly part of the alleged UFO (or some visual phenomena) that occured on June 22, 1976 in the Canary islands?

> (2) If the answer to (1) is no, I would hope for some more context on the origin of this photo or whether it might be a simple photoshop.

Comment: Is this the *only* photograph of the event? Tenerife had a population in the hundreds of thousands, even in the 1970s.  It's difficult to believe that *only one person* took a photo, and that they took *only one photo* of such an unusual event.

Comment: [This](https://en.gyaanipedia.com/wiki/1976_Canary_Island_UFO_sighting) states: *According to the Spanish UFO group Fundación Anomalía, the 22 June sightings, and four other alleged UFO sightings that occurred between 1974 and 1979, correspond directly with times and dates that the US fired submarine based Poseidon intercontinental ballistic missiles from its eastern missile range, which reaches from Cape Canaveral to Ascension Island. Fundación Anomalía cites astrophysicist Jonathan McDowell as having reached this conclusion after obtaining declassified US records.*

Comment: ... the article has many *[citation needed]* remarks, and its 'external links' are broken.

Comment: @WeatherVane your "this" appears to be a spoof site.

Comment: @phoong, are you talking about the Wikipedia like site linked in the comments? Looks to be a legitimate attempt at a Wikipedia like site and not a spoof. Wikipedia makes their platform code usable for anyone to make a Wikipedia clone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Spanish language article](https://naukas.com/2016/06/22/dos-gigantes-rojos-cabalgando-un-misil/) contains more information about the missile launches, including this image of entries in a [database of launches](https://planet4589.org/space/lvdb/index.html) ([see poseidon launches only here](https://planet4589.org/space/lvdb/launch/Poseidon)) compiled by [astrophysicist Jonathan McDowell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_McDowell):

[image]